# Could not find recipe from cookbook when running chef-client

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to test a cookbook on standalone system by using chef-client but keep getting an error for the following command.

I am able to run default.rb by using

```
sudo chef-client -z -o "recipe[kafkaSetup]"
```

But when I run another recipe I get the error as below the following command.

```
sudo chef-client -z -o "recipe[kafkaSetup::reBalanceCluster.rb]"
```

> ```
> [2016-10-18T06:09:33-04:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line, using command line options.
> Starting Chef Client, version 12.12.15
> [2016-10-18T06:09:37-04:00] WARN: Run List override has been provided.
> [2016-10-18T06:09:37-04:00] WARN: Original Run List: []
> [2016-10-18T06:09:37-04:00] WARN: Overridden Run List: [recipe[kafkaSetup::reBalanceCluster.rb]]
> resolving cookbooks for run list: ["kafkaSetup::reBalanceCluster.rb"]
> Synchronizing Cookbooks:
>   - kafkaSetup (0.1.0)
> Installing Cookbook Gems:
> Compiling Cookbooks...
>
> ================================================================================
> Recipe Compile Error
> ================================================================================
>
> Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound
> --------------------------------
> could not find recipe reBalanceCluster.rb for cookbook kafkaSetup
>
> Platform:
> ---------
> x86_64-linux
>
>
> Running handlers:
> [2016-10-18T06:09:37-04:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
> Running handlers complete
> [2016-10-18T06:09:37-04:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
> Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 04 seconds
> [2016-10-18T06:09:37-04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /root/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
> [2016-10-18T06:09:37-04:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
> [2016-10-18T06:09:37-04:00] ERROR: could not find recipe reBalanceCluster.rb for cookbook kafkaSetup
> [2016-10-18T06:09:39-04:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited
> unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
> ```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recipe name does not include the file extension (`.rb`), thus you have to omit it when specifying the run list:

```
sudo chef-client -z -o "recipe[kafkaSetup::reBalanceCluster]"
```

This assumes that there is a file `recipes/reBalanceCluster.rb`. To be save, I would also suggest to use lower case everywhere. That might not work at all. So better rename the file to `rebalancecluster.rb` and use:

```
sudo chef-client -z -o "recipe[kafkaSetup::rebalancecluster]"
```